# Get element from XElement with multiple namespaces

Tags: c#, xml, soap, namespaces

I am receiving SOAP from a web service response but I am not sure how to call it because of the multiple namespaces. Any help is appreciated.

Here's the response:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<S:Envelope xmlns:S="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
   <S:Body>
      <getCompaniesResponse xmlns="http://mastercard.com/sd/pc/service" xmlns:ns2="http://mastercard.com/sd/pc2/service">
         <company>
            <id>123456</id>
            <name>Name is here</name>
            <issuerName>Issuer name is here</issuerName>
         </company>
         <errorMessage xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:nil="true" />
      </getCompaniesResponse>
   </S:Body>
</S:Envelope>
```

Im trying to get the company element from the SOAP. Here's what I have tried so far:

```
        var xe = XElement.Parse(response);
        XNamespace ns = "http://mastercard.com/sd/pc2/service";
        var obj = (string)xe.Descendants(ns + "company").Single();
        Console.WriteLine(obj);
```

In the code above I'm assuming that I only need the last namespace but it returns null. I've also tried to two other namespaces with the same result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Specify the first namespace instead of ns2

```
var xe = XElement.Parse(response);
XNamespace ns = "http://mastercard.com/sd/pc/service";
var obj = (string)xe.Descendants(ns + "company").Single();
Console.WriteLine(obj);
```